# JSTL <c:out> where the element name contains a space character

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have an array of values being made available, but unfortunately some of the variable names include a space.  I cannot work out how to simply output these in the page.  I know I'm not explaining this well (I'm the JSP designer, not the Java coder) so hopefully this example will illustrate what I'm trying to do:

```
<c:out value="${x}"/>
```

outputs to the page (artificially wrapped) as:

```
{width=96.0, orderedheight=160.0, instructions=TEST ONLY. This is a test.,
 productId=10132, publication type=ns, name=John}
```

I can output the name by using

```
<c:out value="${x.name}"/>
```

no problems.  The issue is when I try to get the "publication type"... because it has a space, I can't seem to get `<c:out>` to display it.

I have tried:

```
<!-- error parsing custom action attribute: -->
<c:out value="${x.publication type}"/>
<!-- error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute: -->
<c:out value="${x.publication+type}"/>
<!-- error occurred while parsing custom action attribute: -->
<c:out value="${x.'publication type'}"/>
<!-- error occurred while parsing custom action attribute: -->
<c:out value="${x.publication%20type}"/>
```

I know the real solution is to get the variable names formatted correctly (ie: without spaces) but I can't get the code updated for quite a while.  Can this be done?  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<c:out value="${x['publication type']}"/>
```

I am assuming that a `Map` is the Java type behind this.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for the answer! And in less than 10 minutes.  Wow.

Comment: Glad to help. Java Maps have two different access mechanisms in JSTL, as you've learned. But for a Map key that is a String containing a space, you have to use the [] method of access